# Read txt file with multiple separators

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to read the data to create a plot.

My source data is:

```
["201801",111],["201802",222],["201803",333]
```

I want to create a dataframe like:

```
201801 111

201802 222

201803 333
```

I tried to use

```
df <- read.table('fuel_data.txt',header=FALSE, sep = ",")
```

It doesn't work because `","` is not only used to separate data inside record but also separate different records. Is there a way to read this kind of data into a data frame?

Thanks!

Comment: Very close to a JSON list which would bring something like this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976104/convert-a-character-variable-to-a-list-of-list - into play. No real advantage over the accepted answer here though but `fromJSON(paste0("[", txt, "]"))` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace each [ with a newline and each ] and comma with a space and then read it in:

```
txt <- '["201801",111],["201802",222],["201803",333]'
read.table(text = chartr("[],", "\n  ", txt))
```

giving:

```
      V1  V2
1 201801 111
2 201802 222
3 201803 333
```

Comment: Could you please clarify about how `chartr` works? I've looked at the docs but can't quite see why it's so elegant to use here.

Comment: In `chartr(old, new, x)` it takes the ith character of `old` and the ith character of `new` and replaces one with the other in `x` and does that for all i.

Comment: Thanks! It works. But, when I try to use hist(df) to plot the data. I got the Error: Error in hist.default(df) : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: The first argument of `hist` is a numeric vector, not a data frame.  See `?hist`

Answer (score 2):

Much less beautiful than G. Grothendieck's method:

```
df <- readLines('fuel_data.txt')
df <- gsub("[", "", df, fixed = T)
# change ], for newlines
df <- gsub("],", "\n", df, fixed = T)
df <- gsub("]", "\n", df, fixed = T)
df <- read.table(textConnection(df), sep = ",")
df
# V1  V2
# 1 201801 111
# 2 201802 222
# 3 201803 333
```